# How to effectively query "any" in Django?

Tags: django, any

For example, the query is:

```
a = request.GET['country']
b = request.GET['name']
c = request.GET['title']
...
result = models.Data.objects.filter('country' = a, 'name' = b, 'title' = c, ...)
```

What should I do if one of these *a b c* is "Any"?

I mean if I receive from the frontend, a="Any", how should I effectively free this limit in filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a function to build a [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#q-objects) from a parameter:

```
def _get_filter(name, value):
    return Q() if value == 'Any' else Q((name, value))
```

and combine them with `&`:

```
q = (
    _get_filter('country', request.GET['country']) &
    _get_filter('name', request.GET['name']) &
    _get_filter('title', request.GET['title'])
)

result = models.Data.objects.filter(q)
```

If possible, I’d also get the source of the request (frontend?) to send a better value to indicate “Any”, like an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do everything in a single query.  The query is not run until after everything is done.

You can use:

```
result = models.Data.objects.all()

if a != 'any':
    result = result.filter('country' = a)
if b != 'any':
    result = result.filter('name' = b)
if c != 'any':
    result = result.filter('title' = c)
...
```

The query won't run against the database until everything is finished, so this really doesn't add any extra queries.